# there is a function named addition a and b with the values of 10 and 50, how to run the program with pass statement?

Tags: python, function, arguments, pass-by-reference, addition

Write a function named addition which has two arguments a and b. Don't write anything inside the function use pass statement. Call the function with two values 10 and 50. output is empty and doesn't show any error?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. you didnt ask anything. you didnt provide any code. please review your question

Comment: Can you show us what you got? And the part that didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If that last sentence with the `?` is the question, then the answer is "yes, and that is to be expexcted".

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this

```
def addition(a,b):
  pass
addition(10,50)
```

Comment: then remember to accept as solution too, @ThezooraWorld